# Proof of multiplicative inverse for polar complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing

Use the polar form of complex numbers to show that every complex number $z\neq0$ has multiplicative inverse $z^{-1}$.

If $z=a+bi$, then the polar form is $z=r(\cos(\alpha)+i\sin(\alpha))$.

I can do it, not using polar coordinates:
If $z=a+ib$.

Since $1+0i$ is the multiplicative identity, if $x+iy$ is the multiplicative inverse of $z=a+ib$, then $(a+ib)(x+iy)=1+i0$ $\Rightarrow$ $(ax-by)+i(ay+bx)=1+i0$ $\Rightarrow$ $ax-by=1bx+ay=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $x=\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}$, $y=\frac{-b}{a^2+b^2}$, if $a^2+b^2\neq0$.

Thus, the multiplicative inverse of $a+ib$ is $\frac{a}{a^2+b^2} +\frac{-b}{a^2+b^2}$.

Now, how can I use this information to find it using $z=r(\cos(\alpha)+i\sin(\alpha))$??

I'm stuck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write any non-zero complex number
as 
$z = r e^{i \theta}$
where $r$ and $\theta$ are reals
and $r \ne 0$,
 then
$w = \frac1{r} e^{-i \theta}$
satisfies
$z w = 1$.

You can write this in terms of
$\sin$ and $\cos$,
but I prefer this
if you know that
$e^{i a}
= \cos(a) + i \sin(a)
$.

Answer (score 1):

It is basically the same calculation, $\frac{1}{r}\left(\cos\theta-i\sin\theta\right)$.

We can also view things geometrically. Multiplying by $r\left(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta\right)$ is rotating counterclockwise by $\theta$, and scaling by a factor $r$. To "undo" this, we rotate clockwise by $\theta$, or equivalently counterclockwise by $-\theta$,  and scale by the factor $\frac{1}{r}$. That gives the formula of the first sentence.

Comment: I don't have a good background with polar coordinates, so I'm not sure how to change it all over...?

Comment: You write the complex number as $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}+i\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\right)$. Then $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $\theta$ is the angle whose cosine is $a/r$ and whose sine is $b/r$.